# Possible to redefine \newfont?

Tags: fonts

I have read [TeX Frequently Asked Questions -- What’s wrong with \newfont?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-newfont*), however, I'd still like to know the answer to this. In a style file I'm using there is:

```
\newfont{\myfont}{cmr17 scaled 2000}
```

... however, I'd like to "overload" / redefine this with a smaller scaling (1200) after the style file is loaded (still in the document preamble, though). I guess I'd like to use something like <s>`\renewfont{\myfont}{cmr17 scaled 2000}`</s> - but obviously, \renewfont doesn't exist :)

Since \newfont [defines the command name cmd, *which must not be currently defined*](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-21.html), I guess the answer to the question is negative - but I better make sure and ask:
is there a technique that would allow me to "overload" a font made by `\newfont`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well as the faq mentions `\newfont` is a really simple wrapper around the primitive `\font`. It actually simply adds a test if the font is already defined. So if you want to overwrite the definition simply use the primitive command:

```
\font\myfont=cmr17 scaled 1200 \relax
```

But my advice would be to avoid such hard coded font definitions. They make maintaining a style difficult and - as you see - making small changes awkward.

Comment: Many thanks, @Ulrike Fischer - good to know the 'TeX primitive' way too; cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Joon's Blog: How to undefine a command in LaTeX](http://joonidea.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-undefine-command-in-latex.html), I think I have it:

```
% undefine \myfont
\makeatletter
\let\myfont\@undefined
\makeatother

% ... then define it again: 
\newfont{\myfont}{cmr17 scaled 1200}
```

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: No need for `\makeatletter`: `\let\myfont\relax` is sufficient.

Comment: Many thanks for that @egreg - I'm never exactly sure when to "protect" with `\makeatletter`; good to know it's not needed here... Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This code will make `\xnewfont` have the same syntax as `\newfont`, but it will reject the definition of the control sequence only if it's *not* a font choosing command and, in that case, it will overwrite it.

However, Ulrike's suggestion should be followed: define fonts in term of higher level macros such as `\usefont`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@newfont#1#2{\font#1=#2\relax}
\def\xnewfont#1{%
  \ifdefined#1%
    \def\next{\@iffont{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\next{\@newfont{#1}}%
  \fi\next}
\def\@iffont#1{%
  \edef\next{\meaning#1}\ch@ckiffont
  \if@tempswa
    \def\next{\message{*** Overwriting meaning of font \string#1*** ^^J}%
              \@newfont{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\next{\@ifdefinable#1}%
  \fi\next}
\def\ch@ckiffont{%
  \edef\next{\next\detokenize{select font}\noexpand\@nil}%
  \expandafter\ch@ck@ffont\next}
\begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\ch@ck@ffont##1\detokenize{select font}##2\noexpand\@nil}%
  \x{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Cheers @egreg - looks quite awesome, this code; definitely worth some closer study!